# I search another service like GAE

Tags: language-agnostic

I was planning to use Google App Engine to put an application on their servers.
Alas it is needed to receive a code by SMS to open a GAE account and I have no mobile telephone.

Are there services similar to GAE on which I could open an account ?

Thank you for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

You could Try Amazon EC2

See here also for other alternatives:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine#Competition

Comment: @Daniel Ruf Thank you very much. All that is complex. I will have some reading to do. Do you know if it is easy to use EC2 with Python ?

Comment: we use ruby on rails in our agency, so why dont you try it? but it works there, hopefully there is something for you http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=amazon+ec2+python&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: @Daniel Ruf Reading your link , I learned the existence of Heroku. But I don't know Ruby, only Python. Things concening computing and web applications are rather complex for my understanding, I am quite lost. So I don't think I can learn Ruby rapidly enough to do what I want to do

Comment: well you dont have to learn ruby if you use amazon ec2 or another famous service, you can use also python on amazons server, thats no problem

Comment: Thanks to your link, I was driven to boto, Python interface to AWS. I will be able to use AWS with Python, then. But I have a problem to understand if the EC2 service will allow me to do want I want. I wish to install a program on a server which will periodically connect to one site, and only one site, and that will do web scraping of each udpates of this site. It is a simple and little program, but I need to put it elsewhere than on my own computer because my connectivity to internet is bad and the connection is randomly interrupted. Do you think that EC2 will give me possibility to do that?

Comment: well it it possible but look that you dont reach the limits for the free account and so on, but also read the rules

Comment: When you wrote "why dont you try it", what were you speaking about ? Ruby ?

Comment: no  about python on their servers but theoretically you can run any software on their servers and set them up how you want (os, software packages ...)  we just chose ruby on rails for our project and set up a tomcat server also for a java app

Comment: Rules ? Would it be possible that web scraping would be forbidden with an account on Amazon ?

Comment: dont know, you could ask the amazon support anonymously

Comment: You're a kind person to answer to me. I think the best I have to do is to read the Getting Started documentation and creating an instance to be able to do practical manipulations. And then I will ask questions if I have, but for the moment I am ... in the cloud, I am a little lost in all the existing Amazon services and characteristics